Rider: showing own code style but not ignoring editorconfig
In Rider (JetBrains), I would like to show the code of our projects in a different style than they actually are. We have a linter with quite weird rules. I do accept the linter and I apply it to my code. But when viewing own code, is there some sort of functionality to show it in a different style while not affecting the linter?
Maybe the old {} discussion is a good example.
If the editorconfig says they should be in the next line, but I want them in the same line, the actual code would be:
if(something)
{
  return 40;
}

but viewing the code, it would look like this:
if(something) {
  return 40;
}

I tried a lot of settings in the editor, but I always felt the settings are quite messy, so I didn't find that functionality.
Is this actually possible to achieve?
